# How to Disable touchpad while typing on Aspire One

Tags: touchpad, acer, synaptics, aspire-one

I want to disable the touchpad while I type on my Aspire one netbook.  If I issue the command syndaemon the synaptics driver is not detected:

> Unable to find a synaptics device

So, I added the following to my xorg.conf file:

```
Section "InputDevice"
Identifier "Mouse0"
Driver "synaptics"
Option "Protocol" "auto"
Option "Device" "/dev/input/mouse0"
Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
Option "CorePointer"
Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "1"
EndSection
```

It is still unable to find a synaptics device, however my touchpad works fine.

Comment: Is there a way to force ubuntu to recognize my touchpad, so that I can deactivate it as reccomended.  I guess the touch pad is currently emulating a mouse and so is not shutting off while typing

Comment: Please use the `synaptics` tag instead of `synaptic` to put your question in the list of Synaptics (touchpad) questions, rather than with the Synaptic Package Manager questions. (Oh how I long to have 200 rep so I can just do this housekeeping myself.)

Comment: I had the exact problem with Asus K53S laptop and xserver-xorg-input-synaptics 1.4.1-1, touchpad isn't recognized and thus can not be turned off. After i upgraded to 1.5.0-2, everything works as it should. I suggest to either upgrade to the newest version or to send a bug-report as https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection suggests.

Answer (score 4):

on my lap-top I just go to the System > Prefrences > Mouse and under the Touchpad tab make sure Disable touhpad while typing is checked... after that it automatically disable the touchpad whenever I am typing... pretty cool if you ask me...

Answer (score 4):

You may try reverting the change you did (or keeping it) and installing the [gpointing-device-settings](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpointing-device-settings) package, which will provide more configuration options for your touchpad. Since Ubuntu 10.04 LTS this package replaces `gsynaptics`, if I remember well.

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

Once installed you can find it under **System -> Preferences -> Pointing Devices**.

Answer (score 3):

from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

> The following example invokes
>   syndaemon for 4 seconds after any
>   keyboard activity (-i 4), except when
>   modifier keys such as Alt or Shift are
>   used (-K), and only disables tapping
>   and scrolling (-t) for this period.

```
syndaemon -i 4 -d -t -K
```

add this to your Startup Applications

Comment: This should be chosen as answer.

Answer (score 1):

On my Aspire One netbook, I can just use `Fn+F7` to disable and enable the touchpad.

Comment: thanks, but I really don't want to be pressing some key combination all the time.  I'd like it to be automatically disabled briefly when typing.

Comment: Do you use Gnome or KDE?

Answer (score 0):

Some touchpads emulate a mouse in their hardware/firmware, and because of that still (partially) work even if they aren't recognized as "touchpads".

If GNOME detects a touchpad, it will show the tab in the Mouse preferences as [TheX explains](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7161/how-to-disable-touchpad-while-typing-on-aspire-one/7194#7194).

Answer (score 0):

First entirely undo the current setting: Remove the tick for Disable touchpad while typing in Mouse & Touchpad settings.

Now search for and open Startup Applications from the Dash. Click Add.

```
Name: Syndaemon

Command: syndaemon -i 1.0 -K -R -t

Comment: Disable touchpad while typing, with a reasonable delay and only for tapping and scrolling
```

The -i 1.0 parameter sets the idle time of the keyboard to 1s. -K option ignores the Modifier keys. -R option uses the XRecord extension for detecting keyboard activity instead of polling the keyboard state. -t option disables tapping and scrolling but not mouse movements.

Click Add and then Close.

Reboot your computer.

Note: this is a user preference, so repeat this in every user account.