# ASUS 1018p disable touchpad while typing?

Tags: 11.04, touchpad

How can I automatically disable the touchpad while I typing?

Comment: possible duplicate?  Did you try the answer here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/7161/how-to-disable-touchpad-while-typing-on-aspire-one

Comment: There is no answer for me I use natty. And launchpad says that I already have all packages in natty.

Comment: Now I trying this package "gpointing-device-settings" it does nothing for me. When default mouse settings are not working this could be a bug.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards