# Disable Screen Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, screen

I am a begginer in Ubuntu and I have some dificulties apart from learning the new OS.

How can I disable the touch property of the screen? It has a hardware defect and it thinks that someone is touching the screen constantly. The computer is an ACER Aspire 1825 PTZ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Disable touchpad while typing on Aspire One](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7161/how-to-disable-touchpad-while-typing-on-aspire-one)

Comment: Is this a touchscreen or touchpad?

Answer (score 0):

First list your devices:

`xinput --list-props 14`

look for your device, shoul be called something with touch

```
xinput set-prop 'Your device name' 'Device Enabled' 0
```

Changing the 0 to 1, would enable the device